# Changed the brake caliper on the driver front side of my 2003 Ford Expedition and the wheel wont turn. What's wrong?

Tags: ford, brakes, expidition

Help me find out why my wheel on my 2003 Ford Expedition will not turn after I have changed the brake caliper on the front driver side.

Comment: Did you notice when it stopped turning?  e.g. After fitting the caliper, after fitting the brake pads, after bleeding the brake lines, after pressing the brake hard?

Comment: I'm wondering if one of the slides on the caliper has caused the caliper to stick or cock to one side, causing it to stick. Personally, I'd suggest pulling the caliper off of the caliper bracket and seeing where it is causing the bind. It obviously has to do with the brakes, at least one could assume that due to work just being done on the vehicle.

Comment: Are you able to respond the questions?  Additional information will be required to assist you.

Comment: Please tell us what you did when you changed them. Did you wind the caliper back in when you changed the pads?